# Wolfram wishlist: series of $\Gamma(z)$ in $z=-m$. Cycle index of symmetric groups.

Tags: gamma-function, riemann-zeta, harmonic-numbers, wolfram-alpha, polygamma

I found out that [Wolfram has a wish list](https://functions.wolfram.com/Contribute/topten.html#1) of formulas it is researching.

The first point is "Series for the gamma function"
*We are searching for general formulas for the series expansion of the gamma function $\Gamma(z)$ near its regular points and poles $z=-n / n==0,-1,-2,...$. These formulas should include the psi­functions and their derivatives.*

I calculated it: for $-m=0,-1,-2,...$
$$\Gamma(z)=\frac{(-1)^m}{m!(z+m)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_n(a_1,...,a_n)}{n!}(z+m)^{n}$$
where
$$a_n=(n-1)!\left(H_m^{(n)}+(-1)^n\zeta(n)\right)\qquad\text{where:}\quad\zeta(1)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\zeta(1+h)+\zeta(1-h)}{2}=\gamma$$
equivalently:
$$a_n=(n-1)!H_m^{(n)}+\psi^{(n-1)}(1)$$
Where:

1. $B_n(a_1,...,a_n)$ is the $n$-th complete Bell polynomial
2. $H_m^{(n)}$ is the generalized harmonic number
3. $\zeta(z)$ is the Riemann zeta function
4. $\psi^{(\nu)}(z)$ is the polygamma function

---

**Question**
(I don't think it's possible) Does anyone have any ideas for writing this formula
$$B_n\left(H_m+\psi(1),...,(n-1)!H_m^{(n)}+\psi^{(n-1)}(1)\right)$$
without using Bell polynomials (and without writing a very heavy formula)?

---

PS: (this is a little off topic) I tried to send an email to the link they had put to provide contributions "contributions@functions.wolfram.com"
But I received an email reply with written *The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect*.
Does anyone happen to know some other way to contact them? So I send it to them.

### Update

Considering $$b_n=H_m^{(n)}+(-1)^n\zeta(n)$$

It is possible to write the series as

$$\Gamma(z)=\frac{(-1)^m}{m!(z+m)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}Z(S_n)\cdot (z+m)^{n}$$

Where:

$\displaystyle Z(S_n):=\frac{B_n(0!\cdot b_0, 1!\cdot b_1, ..., (n-1)! \cdot b_{n-1})}{n!}$
is the cycle index of the symmetric group $S_{n}$

Comment: RE your offtopic question, that response suggests that the mailbox is broken. You may want to contact technical support for wolfram.com: https://www.wolfram.com/company/contact/?source=footer

Comment: Also, it seems you rolled back my edit to the link at the top of your post. I recommend accepting the edit - the link you have provided is broken and can't be visited.

Comment: @preferred_anon Ahh ok, I didn't see the difference on the screen and I didn't understand what I changed, that's why I rolled back (now I correct)

Comment: @MathAttack Can you provide a brief derivation of you gamma function series?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ I remember the proof but I don't have it on paper now (I had calculated the series last year for my curiosity, but I found out 2 days ago thanks to your comment to my question on the integral representation of polygamma that Wolfram was interested in)

Comment: Do you happen to be math_notes on instagram?

Comment: @Zima Yes, I manage it, why?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, since you posted this also on insta

Comment: @Zima yes, I had thought of sending it to the wolfram people via Instagram but even there they don't respond, I think it's a bit of a lost cause.